Esp32 strange behavior using two RMT channels simultaneously
I'm using ESP32s2 to drive a WS2812 led chain with RMT. It works just fine. Tx channel is configured as below:
rmt_tx_channel_config_t tx_chan_config = {
        .clk_src = RMT_CLK_SRC_DEFAULT, // select source clock
        .gpio_num = context->led_GPIO,
        .mem_block_symbols = 64, // increase the block size can make the LED less flickering
        .resolution_hz = TICK_RESOLUTION,
        .trans_queue_depth = 4, // set the number of transactions that can be pending in the background
    };

However, while I'm trying to read an IR remote control with chennel configured like this:
rmt_rx_channel_config_t rx_channel_cfg = {
        .clk_src = RMT_CLK_SRC_DEFAULT,
        .resolution_hz = IR_RESOLUTION_HZ,
        .mem_block_symbols = 64, 
        .gpio_num = IR_PIN,
    };

apparently leds stops to work, and remote is not received. Code works on an esp32 dev board.
What am I doing wrong? Can I use two channel simultaneously?
